# Optimize Function in Python

Tags: python, function

I have the following function in Python that works properly. How can I improve the syntax so that it performs better or summarizes the number of lines?

```
    def my_function(path):                

        with open(path) as f:
            count = sum(line.count(";") for line in f)

        query = open(path).read()

        for i, query in enumerate(query.split(';')):
            print(i," de ",count)

            do_something(query)
```

Comment: Questions about improving working code are a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks! i will post there

Comment: Remove blank lines...

Comment: The same question was posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/235575/optimize-function-in-python